# Determine whether a function template has been instantiated in another translation unit

Tags: c++, templates, linker

A library (which I don't control) has a customization point enabled by ADL. The default implementation has incorrect behavior for one specific type (which, again, I don't control) so I provide an implementation of the customization point:

```cpp
// their.hpp
namespace their::adl { struct tag {}; }
namespace their {
template<class T>
void customization_point(T, adl::tag) {
    std::println("default implementation (wrong for another::C)");
}
void interface(auto x) { customization_point(x, adl::tag()); }
}
```

```cpp
// another.hpp
namespace another { class C {}; }
```

```cpp
// my_implementation.hpp
namespace their::adl { // permitted reopening
inline void customization_point(another::C, their::adl::tag) {
    std::println("my implementation for another::C");
}
}
```

However, other code may call into the library without including my customization point implementation, causing ODR violation and potentially inconsistent behavior:

```cpp
// other.cpp
#include <their.hpp>
#include <another.hpp>
// no #include <my_implementation.hpp>
void f() { their::interface(another::C()); }
```

I could fully-specialize `their::customization_point<another::C>` to provide an overriding strong symbol but that would fail to have the desired effect if the (incorrect) customization point call has been inlined into `their::interface<another::C>`:

```cpp
// my_override.cpp
namespace their {
template<> void customization_point<another::C>(another::C, adl::tag) {
    std::println("my override for another::C");
}
}
```

Is there a way to determine whether `their::customization_point` has been instantiated for template argument `another::C` and, if so, cause link failure? That is, is there something I can add to my program that will cause link failure, without any modification to the TU other.cpp? I'm OK with non-portable solutions (but would prefer something that works with gcc on Linux) and would prefer something that works with only the compiler (so preferably no linker scripts).

So far, the only thing I've come up with is to use `[[gnu::weak]]` attribute to check whether a weak symbol for the template function instantiation has been emitted. I can use that to cause the program to abort early at startup, but I'd prefer to catch the error during build if possible:

```cpp
// load_fail.cpp
namespace their {
template<> [[gnu::weak]] void customization_point<another::C>(another::C, adl::tag);
static int unused = static_cast<void (*)(another::C, adl::tag)>(
    &customization_point<another::C>) ? (std::abort(), 0) : 0;
}
```